# Integrate fit.Svensson in Matlab

Tags: matlab

For my thesis I want to calculate the spot rates via SvenssonModel of Swiss Government Bonds. For this I have taken the fitSvensson function.... Actually I've taken the example from the matlab-help-hompage (http://ch.mathworks.com/help/fininst/fitsvenssonirfunctioncurve.html?refresh=true)

But the problem is, that this example just gives me the "yields of the bonds" but I want the "spot rates"... I know that I just have to integrate the whole thing.... On the homepage (see link above) they mention at the part "more about" as follows:
-> "this can be integrated to derive an equation for the zero curve"

This is my code:

```
Settle = datenum('2014,6,13');
Maturity = datemnth(Settle,12*[0.991780822 1.747945205 2.334246575 2.980821918...
3.575342466 4.915068493 6.068493151 6.879452055 7.953424658 8.671232877...
10.00273973 11.12054795 11.96438356 13.04657534 13.83013699 17.03561644...
18.83287671 21.75068493 23.05479452 27.89863014 34.59178082 50.06849315]');
CleanPrice = [103.8388 105.2390 106.2400 112.8682 111.9102 114.1410 113.8762...
111.2851 111.9671 130.4220 104.9018 107.9665 103.3728 130.0583 137.9233...
117.1945 136.5379 120.9674 97.5021 100.7388 167.5365 116.7462]';
CouponRate = [0.0375 0.0250 0.0200 0.0425 0.0300 0.0300 0.0225 0.0200...
0.0200 0.0400 0.0125 0.0150 0.0125 0.0325 0.0400 0.0225 0.0350 0.0250...
0.0125 0.0150 0.0400 0.0200]';


Instruments = [(repmat(Settle,22,1)) Maturity CleanPrice CouponRate];
PlottingPoints = datemnth(Settle,1:360);
% X-Achse Zeitraum
% 1:360 -> 2045; 1:180 -> 2030; 1:90 -> 2022; 1:45 -> 2019
Yield = bndyield(CleanPrice,CouponRate,Settle,Maturity);

SvenssonModel = IRFunctionCurve.fitSvensson('Zero',Settle,Instruments);

SvenssonModel.Parameter

% create the plot
plot(PlottingPoints, getParYields(SvenssonModel, PlottingPoints),'g')
hold on
scatter(Maturity,Yield,'black')
datetick('x')
legend({'Svensson Fitted Curve','Yields'},'location','best')
```

and this is what I have done to integrate... but actually it doesn't work

```
%Integral

fun = @(bndyield)('Zero',repmat(Settle,22,1),Instruments);
b = integral(fun,Settle,Maturity,'ArrayValued',false
```

Comment: Don't know much about what is the spot rate, but the function does have optional parameters : FitType (Optional) Price, Yield, or DurationWeightedPrice determines which is minimized in the curve fitting process. Is it none of the things in there?

Answer (score 0):

Spot (=Zero coupon) rates of the bonds can be easily retrieved with:

```
spotrates = SvenssonModel.getZeroRates(Maturity);
```

If you need more insights into the math behind it, the documentation for the package termstrc (although written for R), gives a good overview over the computational steps of the Svensson model.
http://www.jstatsoft.org/v36/i01/paper